# Render different components for each section of React Native SectionList

Tags: reactjs, react-native, render, react-native-sectionlist

I am building a section list. Each section has a different data object with varying values. Because of that I need to render a different component for each section but am having a hard time figuring out how to do so.

Here is my `DATA` array (two are dummies for now)

```
const DATA = [
{
  title: "Groups",
  data: [
    {
      groupName: "Samwise",
    },
    
  ],
},
{
  title: "Noters"
    {
      userName: "Merri",
    },
  ],
},
{
  title: "Contacts",
  data: termIsContact.length ? termIsContact : contacts,
}]
```

SectionList component

```
<SectionList
  sections={DATA}
  keyExtractor={(item, index) => item + index}
  renderItem={renderItem}
  renderSectionHeader={({ section: { title } }) => (
    <View style={tw.style(`justify-center bg-red-100 pl-4`, { height: 28 })}>
      <Text style={tw`text-base font-bold`}>{title}</Text>
    </View>
  )}
/>
```

How I am rendering the Contacts list

```
const Item = ({ givenName, familyName }) => (
  <TouchableOpacity
    onPress={() => toggleContact(`${givenName} ${familyName}`)}
    style={tw.style("justify-start pl-4 w-full flex flex-row items-center", {
      height: 56,
      borderBottomColor: "#aaaaaa",
      borderBottomWidth: 1,
    })}
  >
    <Avatar
      name={`${givenName} ${familyName}`}
      size={32}
      backgroundColor={"#D9F3FC"}
      labelColor={"#16ade0"}
    />

    <Text style={tw.style("text-black text-base pl-2", {})}>
      {givenName} {familyName}
    </Text>
  </TouchableOpacity>
)

const renderItem = ({ item }) => <Item familyName={item.familyName} givenName={item.givenName} />
```

My thinking is to create an `<Item />` to be rendered for each of the sections but just cant figure out how to get each section to render its own style from the data in that sections data object.

Thank you very much in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the solution and hope this is helpful to someone in the future looking for the same.

The sections array allows each object in it to take in a prop `renderItem` so you can create a unique component for each section.

**My Component**

```
const NotersItem = ({ userName }) =>
searchTerm && !termIsUser.length ? (
  <></>
) : (
  <TouchableOpacity
    onPress={() => toggleContact(`${userName}`)}
    style={tw.style("justify-start pl-4 w-full flex flex-row items-center", {
      height: 48,
      borderBottomColor: "#aaaaaa",
      borderBottomWidth: 1,
    })}
  >
    <Avatar name={`${userName}`} size={32} backgroundColor={"#D9F3FC"} labelColor={"#16ade0"} />

    <Text style={tw.style("text-black text-base pl-2", {})}>{userName}</Text>
  </TouchableOpacity>
)

  const renderNotersItem = ({ item }) => <NotersItem userName={item.userName} />
```

**Section Array**

```
  const DATA = [
{
  title: "Groups",
  renderItem: renderGroupItem,
  data: termIsGroup.length ? termIsGroup : groups,
},
{
  title: "Highnoters",
  renderItem: renderNotersItem,
  data: termIsUser.length ? termIsUser : users,
},
{
  title: "Contacts",
  renderItem: renderContactItem,
  data: termIsContact.length ? termIsContact : contacts,
},
```

]

**SectionList component**

```
      sections={DATA}
      keyExtractor={(item, index) => item + index}
      renderItem={({ section: { renderItem } }) => <View>{renderItem}</View>}
      renderSectionHeader={({ section }) => (
        <View style={tw.style(`justify-center bg-red-100 pl-4`, { height: 28 })}>
          <Text style={tw`text-base font-bold`}>{section.title}</Text>
        </View>
      )}
    />
```

Any questions please comment!